# What is the differences between Spring Boot API without Filter and Spring Boot API with Filter?

Tags: spring-boot

From the beginning, I often write Spring Boot API with many API depend on what my application needs. I know there is a type like Filter Servlet, what is it? Can anyone help me to find the difference between API with Filter and without Filter?

I have go through some research: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_servlet_filter.htm

I have a sample for using Servlet Filter: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product#create-2019-10

Comment: What is your research, please show here. Did you try Googling it?
Link for you :https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/servlet/java-servlet-filter-example/

Comment: Yes, I did but I don't think there are many advantages to use Filter or perhaps I don't understand or recognize the advantages yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A filter is an object used to intercept the HTTP requests and responses of your application. By using filter, we can perform two operations at two instances −

```
Before sending the request to the controller
Before sending a response to the client.
```

so its depends on requirement of your app if you need to do some work before sending request to controller or not.

Take an example below:
if we need to create an application where we need to **authenticate and authorization of user** with help of **token** so in each api we need to verify token before sending request to controller so we can use filter their.

and sending response back to client if we want to append some token then we can add same in filter.

example of filter:
https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-add-filter/

below method use for next call:
**filterChain.doFilter(request, response);**

Comment: Can you show a simple example for me? Because in the past the requirement can be big or small I still could do it without Servlet Filter.

Comment: So if I understand correctly: Servlet Filter will check If the token is verified or not if verified next step will be the do what the request call.